# how to update UI more efficiently

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I am  re-using a `my_layout.xml` with two different ViewModel & LiveData
in which function should I update my UI `onCreate()`/`onStart()`/`onResume()` (& why??), so won't be redundant...

Comment: AFAIK state Flows and Coroutines are used to get update as fast as possible

Comment: What to you mean by re use layout?. receive your observer in onCreate()

Comment: @Vikas imean  one.xml  used by  2 different fragmentClass in 1 ActivityClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `Observer`s on your `LiveData` in `onCreate` (or something like `onViewCreated` in a Fragment). Those observer functions should update the UI when a new value comes in, so you just write the function telling it how to update - display this value in this `TextView`, that kind of thing).

Once you've wired that up, the UI will update itself as the `LiveData` changes. And if those `LiveData`s already have data, you'll get it as soon as you call `observe` - so the update function will run and initialise your UI with the current data.

You just need to have references to your inflated views (like the `TextView` you want to update) so you can use them in the update functions. That's why it has to be after you've called `setContentView` in `onCreate`, or in `onViewCreated` in a fragment, where you have access to the inflated `view`.

`LiveData` (and any other lifecycle-aware components) will automatically update when you go from `onStop` to `onResume` etc, and your updates will just happen

Comment: thnx buddy for this lvl of explanation..........:)
its really helpful